# Display for programmers?

Tags: displays

I'm planning to buy a laptop. And I picked Dell Precision. As a programmer, I spend hours working on the laptop.

I'm unable to select the display from the below options,

[image]

I'm not aware of the terms WVA, LBL, sRGB, nit, NTSC, WLAN, WWAN to pick the good display.

What would be the preferable display, touch or non-touch? Which would be the best display option that I can opt for.

Preferably,
I'm looking for a display which doesn't affect eyes.

Comment: Higher brightness (nits) is useful if you're working in bright environments, like if the sun is shining directly on the screen. "WVA" vs "TN" may come down to personal preference. Neither are fantastic for viewing angles. (Which matters for touch/tablet style laptops) None of these specify anti-glare coatings, but I would expect the "Touch" options have a glossy or glass-like layer over them. (Avoid if you want to reduce glare)

Comment: What is the preferable sRGB?

Comment: NTSC and sRGB are the color spaces. A 100% sRGB screen can produce about the same number of colours as a 72% NTSC screen. I think 45% NTSC would be worse than 100% sRGB, I'm not completely sure of that though.

Comment: @Romen, what would be the preferable display, touch or non-touch?

Comment: That depends on whether you want a touchscreen.